# What is the Data Type Length in Java

Tags: java, type-conversion, abstract-data-type

Hi Friends I want to know the All Data Types and Its total length in Java (MAX and MIN)
for example 
Long -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807
could you please help me friends.

Comment: use google. it has answers

Comment: Why do you feel that we would be able to give a better answer than the official java doc? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @Ray Why should OP be something else than lazy when his bad question still got 2 Upvotes? This is one thing you should remember on Stack Overflow: It doesn't matter how bad your question is, there is always someone who thinks that this is a good question. (And yes, this is very very sad)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/language/java-data.html) . 
If you use unsigned type the just calculate 
 
`ans = (2 power number_of_bits) - 1` 
 else calculate  
`ans = (2 power number_of_bits - 1)` 
 and the range is 
 `[-ans,ans-1]` 
have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, it is the official documentation by oracle, where it is explained in detail.

[Source Link - Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

For a quick reference, quoting the main points from the documentation.

**byte**:

The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a **minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127** (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form of documentation.

**short**:

The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a **minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of 32,767** (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the memory savings actually matters.

**int**:

By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a **minimum value of -231 and a maximum value of 231-1**. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic operations for unsigned integers.

**long**:

The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a **minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of 263-1**. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support arithmetic operations for unsigned long.

**float**:

The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double) if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers. This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform.

**double**:

The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats, and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned above, this data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency.

**boolean**:

The boolean data type has only two possible values: true and false. Use this data type for simple flags that track true/false conditions. This data type represents one bit of information, but its "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.

**char**:

The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a **minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff'** (or 65,535 inclusive).

In addition to the eight primitive data types listed above, the Java programming language also provides special support for character strings via the java.lang.String class. Enclosing your character string within double quotes will automatically create a new String object; for example, String s = "this is a string";. String objects are immutable, which means that once created, their values cannot be changed. The String class is not technically a primitive data type, but considering the special support given to it by the language, you'll probably tend to think of it as such. You'll learn more about the String class in Simple Data Objects

Answer (score 1):

I think you could find all the information though this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

- byte: The byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer.
  It has a minimum value of -128 and a maximum value of 127
  (inclusive). The byte data type can be useful for saving memory in
  large arrays, where the memory savings actually matters. They can
  also be used in place of int where their limits help to clarify your
  code; the fact that a variable's range is limited can serve as a form
  of documentation.
- short: The short data type is a 16-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of -32,768 and a maximum value of
  32,767 (inclusive). As with byte, the same guidelines apply: you can
  use a short to save memory in large arrays, in situations where the
  memory savings actually matters.
- int: By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer, which has a minimum value of -231 and a maximum
  value of 231-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the int data type
  to represent an unsigned 32-bit integer, which has a minimum value of
  0 and a maximum value of 232-1. Use the Integer class to use int data
  type as an unsigned integer. See the section The Number Classes for
  more information. Static methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned
  etc have been added to the Integer class to support the arithmetic
  operations for unsigned integers.
- long: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The signed long has a minimum value of -263 and a maximum value of
  263-1. In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to
  represent an unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and
  a maximum value of 264-1. Use this data type when you need a range of
  values wider than those provided by int. The Long class also contains
  methods like compareUnsigned, divideUnsigned etc to support
  arithmetic operations for unsigned long.
- float: The float data type is a single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
  discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats,
  and Values section of the Java Language Specification. As with the
  recommendations for byte and short, use a float (instead of double)
  if you need to save memory in large arrays of floating point numbers.
  This data type should never be used for precise values, such as
  currency. For that, you will need to use the java.math.BigDecimal
  class instead. Numbers and Strings covers BigDecimal and other useful
  classes provided by the Java platform.
- double: The double data type is a double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point. Its range of values is beyond the scope of this
  discussion, but is specified in the Floating-Point Types, Formats,
  and Values section of the Java Language Specification. For decimal
  values, this data type is generally the default choice. As mentioned
  above, this data type should never be used for precise values, such
  as currency.
- boolean: The boolean data type has only two possible values: true and false. Use this data type for simple flags that track true/false
  conditions. This data type represents one bit of information, but its
  "size" isn't something that's precisely defined.
- char: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of
  '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

Comment: what about `String`, `BigDecimal`, `BigInteger`...?

Comment: The Object class does not define a length field, and an Object does not have one. The length field is defined for arrays types only. It is a defined implicitly.

The particular case of BigInteger, is that it internally uses an int[] to represent the huge numbers you use. Thus it really depends on the size of the number you store in it.

Comment: but they are all limited in some ways, mostly by your memory

Comment: Yes, but that is something different than the question asked. He wanted to know about lengths and Object class doesn't define a length. So yes, they are all limited by your memory, but it depends on the values of each object. Do you agree?

Comment: yes, but they should still be mentioned. i would guess he had the homework to find out all datatypes and their length (had this task too). and therefore they should at least be mentioned with no fixed length

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access minimum / maximum values at run-time, most of the wrapper classes have static final MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE constants:

```
    System.out.println("Float min value : " + Float.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Float.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Integer min value : " + Integer.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Double min value : " + Double.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Double.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Byte min value : " + Byte.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Byte.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Long min value : " + Long.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("Short min value : " + Short.MIN_VALUE + ", max value :" + Short.MAX_VALUE);
```